# Update All records Django Orm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to update `is_active` to `True` which is inside `User` Model (Auth Table) whose `user_company` is `5`. There are lots of users having same company id's

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_role = models.ForeignKey(ACLRoles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_profiles/', default='default_user.png',blank=True, null=True)
    user_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering it's a one time thing you have to do:

1. First in cmd type:

   ```
   python manage.py shell
   ```

   it will open a python shell to type python script.
2. Now in shell type:

   ```
   >>> from appropriate.place import User  // import the auth User model from wherever it is in your project
   >>> users_to_activate = User.objects.filter(userprofile__user_company_id=5).update(is_active=True)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`update()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) on a queryset:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user_company_id=5).update(user_is_deleted=True)
```

Comment: How can i update `user__is_active` user is Auth Table

Comment: `User.objects.filter(userprofile__user_company_id=5).update(is_active=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user_company__pk=5).update(user_is_deleted=True)
```